# Finding the right git workflow

Tags: git, git-branch

We are a small web app team (less than 10).  Our environment consists of 3 test environments and Production for a dozen apps.  One of our test environments is customer facing for feature/hotfix approval (Call it Dev) and the other two are hidden test environments, one for Dev (Call it Pre-Dev) and one for Production (Call it Pre-Production).  This helps us ensure the feature/bug is fairly vetted.  Each feature flows through these 3 test environments before hitting Production and some features can take months to be approved by the customer.

We need a strategy that lets us implement features that stay in testing for a long time while also implementing short term features and quick bug fixes during our iterations with minimal overhead.

We currently have one branch per environment and use pull requests from our feature/bugfix branches to distribute our new code to each branch one by one.  When releasing, anything in Pre-Prod branch gets squashed into Prod and released.  We are looking at trunk based workflow but our long term testing hold us up I think.  Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need 2 things:

1. A cleaner (simpler) git-flow
2. A strict separation of config from code

---

### 1. Simplest git flow

Feature/Bugfixes

- Anything in the `master` branch is deployable
- To work on something new, create a descriptively named branch off of master (ie: bugfix_login_error)
- Commit to that branch locally and regularly push your work to the same named branch on the server
- When you need feedback or help, or you think the branch is ready for merging, open a pull request (or merge request in GitLab).
- At this point `rebase` to get latest changes of master in the feature/bugfix branch.
- After someone else has reviewed and signed off on the feature, you can merge it into `master`

Hotfixes

- Hotfix branches are created from the `master` branch.
- Every hotfix branch must merge back into master and all feature/bugfix branches

The idea is to keep it really really simple for everyone on the team to understand i.e. the only way to reduce human errors. See [github-flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html) for more detail on this approach.

> Rule of thumb: KISS (Keep It Stupid Simple)

---

#### 2. DO NOT keep one branch per environment

store `config` in the environment variables. Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any code; unlike config files, there is little chance of them being checked into the code repo accidentally.

See [The Twelve-factor app](https://12factor.net/) for more detail on this approach.

> A litmus test for whether an app has all config correctly factored out of the code is whether the codebase could be made open source at any moment, without compromising any credentials.